# Discrete Mathematics - Introductory Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am a bit new to the Discrete Mathematics approach. We are given 5 techniques:

```
1) Direct Proof (Such as Completing the Square, Quadratic Formulae, etc.)
2) Proof by Contrapositive
3) Proof by Contradiction
4) Counter Example
5) Proof By Cases
```

Any one is really okay with me. The problem at hand is

Consider the statement: For all integers $n$, if $n$ is even then $8n$ is even.

We know that the integer $8$ is even because it is divisible by $1$,$2$,$4$ and itself.

By definition of any *even* number, we have: $n=2k$

With this we can begin to apply the aforementioned problem:

$n=8(2k)$

And then I can continue on and square both sides
$n^2=8^2*2^2*k^2$

where $k$ is an integer, then so is $8k^2$

I'm not sure? Could someone help guide me in the right direction? Any proof is sufficient, but how would I perform all proofs (if I might be so bold as to ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you're asked to prove is that **if** $n$ is even **then** $8n$ is even.

It is a good idea to think about the "direction" of implication. What are you trying to prove and what do you know?

In this case, we are given that $n$ is even, and we want to show that $8n$ is even.

If $n$ is even then we know that we can write $n = 2k$ for some integer $k$. Upon multiplying by $8$, can we write our new integer as a multiple of $2$? If $n = 2k$ then $8n = 8\times 2k = 16k$. Clearly now we can see that $8n$ is even because $16k = 2\times 8k$ and since $8k$ is an integer, we have written $8n$ as $2$ times an integer, so $8n$ is even.

Comment: What proof is this, exactly? Is the converse true? I would assume that it is not!

Comment: This is a direct proof; you've taken your assumption and directly shown that the implication is true. The converse statement is "If $8n$ is even then $n$ is even", but clearly this isn't true; take if $8n = 24$ then $n = 3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Go ahead and try to prove that if $n$ is even then $n^2$ is even. Write down what you know, write down what you want to show, and try to get from one thing to the next.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach here seems like an attempt at direct proof. But you need not square both sides. It is enough that if $n$ is even, we can write $n=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $8n=8\cdot 2k = 2\cdot (8k)=2j$. Hence, by the definition of an even number $8n$ is even since $8n=2j$ where $j=8k\in\mathbb{Z}$. In other words, $8n$ can be written as an integer that has at least one factor of $2$.

For the other proof types, it is important to work through them. But here are the general constructs. Use these as a guide and try to write out the proofs on your own where applicable. You may assume $p$ is the statement $n$ is even, and $q$ is the statement $8n$ is even.

Direct proof:
$p\Rightarrow q$

Assume $p$ and show that $q$ is true as a result.

Contrapositive:
$\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p$

Assume $q$ is not true, then show that $p$ is not true as a result.

Contradiction: Assume $p \land \neg q$, derive a contradiction, finding that  $p \land \neg q$ is thus impossible, we can conclude $p \Rightarrow q$, since $p \land \neg q$ is the negation of $p \Rightarrow q$.

Counter example:
Used to prove a statement is false. In this case your statement is true. Your counter example will depend on what your are trying to disprove. For instance, if you have a statement with the $\forall$ (for all) qualifier, then finding the existence of something for which the statement is not true disproves the statement.

Proof by cases: Just like it sounds. Due to the structure of the statement, you may need to enumerate cases exhaustively, proving each of them true. In each case, you may use one of the aforementioned proof constructs, or some other proof construct.